# Windows Homegroup

Tags: windows-7, windows-8.1, homegroup

I have 4 PCs, 3 running in Windows 8.1 Pro and 1 in Windows 7 Professional.

I have a Homegroup setup which the 3 that is running on Windows 8.1 Pro have already connected. However, the 1 PC that is running on Windows 7 cannot join in the same homegroup. Telling me that the password is incorrect.

Is it impossible to join different OSes in one homegroup?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17145/windows-homegroup-from-start-to-finish) manual from Microsoft - it is possible:

"After you create a homegroup, the other PCs running Windows 10, Windows 8.1, Windows RT 8.1, or Windows 7 on your network can join it."

Comment: So how come it is telling me that my password is correct which is however correct?

Comment: I think [this post](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/homegroup-not-accepting-password/fd1c1445-3923-40ac-bcfe-06d951ef4f1e?auth=1) could help you.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.

Answer (score 0):

I somehow solved the problem.
The Windows 7 PC has a different time and timezone setting. So I managed to reconfigure it and it is fixed.